# SED or AWK script to extract contact information from huge file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I wants to process a huge text file contains student information by extracting important contact numbers.

**Scenario:**

I've student records (> 1 million) in students.txt. In This file (each line) has

- characters 1 to 10 - Student ID (length 10)
- Character 11 - Grade (length 1)
- Character 12 to 21 - Mobile Number (length 10)
- characters 22 to 24 - Currency Code (length 3)
- Character 25 to 34 - Home phone Number (length 10)
- Character 35 to 37 - Area code (length 3)
- Character 38 to 47 - office phone Number (length 10)

so on

**students.txt**

```
1000000001A9234567890XXX5782463562...
1000000002B9325788532YYY...
1000000001C9234567890XXX6478542698XDE4578954568...
.
.
.
10010000008Z766443367ZZZ...
```

I want to extract contact numbers based on grade

> **Grade A** - Extract Character 12 to 21 - **Mobile Number** (length 10) and Character 25 to 34 - **Home phone Number** (length 10)
>
> **Grade B** - Extract only **mobile number** Character 12 to 21 - Mobile Number (length 10)
>
> **Grade C** - Extract Character 12 to 21 - **Mobile Number** (length 10) and Character 25 to 34 - **Home phone Number** and Character 38 to 47 - **office phone Number** (length 10)

Don't extract anything for other grades.

I wanted the extracted output in a single file which has unique contact numbers

**output: important_contacts.txt**

```
9234567890
5782463562
9325788532
6478542698
4578954568
```

Could anyone please assist me on this?

**Note:** Each **students.txt** contains more than **2.5 Million records**

Comment: You have to show what you've tried and how it failed; currently, this is just a job description for somebody to do all the work.

Comment: The question as it stands is extremely broad. If you make an attempt at a solution and come back with a specific programming problem you'll get a better reception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ***GNU*** `awk` you can extract field values from fixed-width data using the built-in `FIELDWIDTHS` variable. The following one-liner do the task you want:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS = "10 1 10 3 10 3 10" } { if ($2 == "A") print $3 ORS $5; else if ($2 == "B") print $3; else if ($2 == "C") print $3 ORS $5 ORS $7; }' students-3M.txt > numbers.txt
```

You can provide space-separated numbers specifiing the width of each field in the records: `FIELDWIDTHS = "10 1 10 3 10 3 10"`.
We do this in the `BEGIN` rule before any input record is read.
Then the desired fields (columns) could be printed based on your rules using `if else if` construct.
For grades where multiple phone numbers are required on a new line we print our fields with the built-in output record separator `ORS` that is a new line by default.

**Also** you can save the following script into a file e.g. `get-contacts.awk`

```
BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS = "10 1 10 3 10 3 10" }
{ 
    if ($2 == "A") {
        print $3 ORS $5
    } else if ($2 == "B") {
        print $3
    } else if ($2 == "C") {
        print $3 ORS $5 ORS $7
    }
}
```

***And call it:***

```
awk -f get-contacts.awk students-3M.txt > numbers.txt
```

I generated 3M rows ***test data*** with the following `php` script:

```
<?php

for ($i=0; $i < 3000000; $i++) { 
    $gr = strtoupper(substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),1));
    $pn = rand(1,9999999999);
    $hn = rand(1,9999999999);
    $on = rand(1,9999999999);
    printf("100%07d%s%010dXXX%010dXDE%010d\n",$i,$gr,$pn,$hn,$on);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it in principal:

```
echo '1000000001A9234567890XXX5782463562... 
1000000002B9325788532YYY... 
1000000001C9234567890XXX6478542698XDE4578954568... ' | sed -n -r 's/[0-9]{10}A([0-9]{9}).*/\1/p'
923456789
```

or with a file:

```
sed -n -r 's/[0-9]{10}A([0-9]{9}).*/\1/p' file > gradeA.txt
```

- sed -n surpresses output which doesn't match.
- -r activates extended regexes
- s/.../.../ substitutes part 1 with 2
- [0-9] describes a character which is a cipher
- {10} means, we want 10 ciphers
- A is just the A grade
- (...) is a capturing group, the first one, later referenced with \1
- and it is digits, and of length 9
- .* matches anything, here: the rest of the line
- missing: the characters to skip, the definition of the second number.

You write one such program per Grade to extract and output to different files.

Million lines isn't a problem for sed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this and update here.

Answer (score 0):

Your could pass your input file "students.txt" to a shell script, which reads the records line by line and parses the data according to grade. Then just extract the substrings you want via shell parameter expansion '$'.

Without getting into the exact nature of your specific dataset consider the following input file **students.txt**:

```
StudentID123GradeAPhonenumber123
StudentID456GradeBPhonenumber456
StudentID789GradeCPhonenumber789
StudentID321GradeAPhonenumber312
StudentID654GradeBPhonenumber654
StudentID987GradeCPhonenumber987
```

And this script **parse_grades.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read -r line; do
    # save a line
    PERSON=$line

    # extract the grade
    GRADE=${PERSON:17:1}

    # and now process it
    if [ "$GRADE" = "A" ]; then
        # show student ID and grade
        DATA_GRADE_A=${PERSON:0:18}
        echo $DATA_GRADE_A >> outputfile.txt
    fi
    if [ "$GRADE" = "B" ]; then
        # only show phone number
        DATA_GRADE_B=${PERSON:18:14}
        echo $DATA_GRADE_B >> outputfile.txt
    fi
    if [ "$GRADE" = "C" ]; then
        # show StudentID and PhoneNo
        SID=${PERSON:0:12}
        PHONENO=${PERSON:18:14}
        DATA_GRADE_C=$SID$PHONENO
        echo $DATA_GRADE_C >> outputfile.txt
    fi
done < "$1"

exit 0
```

Make the script executable with:

```
chmod +x parse_grades.sh
```

And pass your input file to it:

```
parse_grades.sh students.txt
```

Based upon above recordset, you should get the following result in outputfile.txt:

```
StudentID123GradeA
Phonenumber456
StudentID789Phonenumber789
StudentID321GradeA
Phonenumber654
StudentID987Phonenumber987
```

The script's core idea is making use of ${VAR:Offset:Length}

Now all you need to do, is adjust the numbers according to your specific requirements.

Check

```
man bash
```

or this website for more information

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this and update here.